# Run Scriptblock in It's Own Instance and Return ExitCode to Parent Script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to have a PowerShell script as a node inside of an XML file that either returns an exit code of 1 or 0. I would then like to run this script in an instance separate from the parent PS script but return its exit code back to the parent instance so that I can write an If statement based on the ExitCode.

Right now I made the XML PowerShell script simple (this seems to be working fine without any issues):

```
exit 1
```

Here's my code in the parent PS script:

```
#write XML script to string then convert string to scriptblock
[String]$installCheck_ScriptString = $package.installcheck_script
$installCheck_Script = [Scriptblock]::Create($installCheck_ScriptString)

#start new instance of powershell and run script from XML
$process = (Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-command {$installCheck_Script} -PassThru -Wait")
$installCheck_ScriptResult = $process.ExitCode

If ($installCheck_ScriptResult -gt 0)
    {
    ....
    }
```

In playing around with the code, I seem to either get a message that Wait or Passthru are unexpected tokens or I don't get any ExitCode value. `$LastExitCode` always returns a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Wait` and `-PassThru` are not valid parameters for `powershell.exe`. Did you mean to apply them to `Start-Process` like this?

```
$process = (Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-command {$installCheck_Script}" -PassThru -Wait)
```

Note that you're going to have some issues with this approach. If `$installCheck_Script` contains any characters that need to be escaped you're going to be doing a lot of checks and replaces.

You could avoid that by using `-EncodedCommand` with `powershell.exe` and passing in the base64 encoded version of the script:

```
$encodedScript = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($installCheck_Script))
$process = (Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand",$encodedScript -PassThru -Wait)
```

But only do this if you're insistent on calling via shell.

### A better (?) way:

As an alternative to what you're doing (shelling out), you might consider creating a job, and then instead of using an exit code, use an actual return value:

```
$installCheck_Script = " 1 " # for example
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($installCheck_Script)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
$job | Wait-Job
$code = $job | Receive-Job
```

If you wanted better performance you could do it in process with runspaces. This is made easier with the [PoshRSJob Module](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) which lets you use runspaces in a similar way to using jobs.